# How to express "to squeeze his skin / hand... with my fingernails"?

Tags: word-request, phrase-request

> > [squeeze](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/squeeze_1?q=squeeze)
>
> [transitive, intransitive] squeeze (something) to press something
>   firmly, especially with your fingers
>
> to squeeze a tube of toothpaste
>
> to squeeze the trigger of a gun (= to fire it)
>
> He squeezed her hand and smiled at her.
>
> Just take hold of the tube and squeeze.

Look at this picture

[image]

We may want to say "**she is squeezing my arm with her hands**" to depict the above picture.

Now, how to express "**she is squeezing my arm with her fingernails**".?

Do we have a separate term for that action or we just say  "**to squeeze his skin / hand... with my fingernails**"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would describe the images above as *digging her nails into her arms*.

> She squeezed my arm, digging her nails into me.

To squeeze with *only* your fingernails or the tips of your fingers would be to *pinch* somebody.